# Mock the blob storage bindings in azure functions core tools

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Azure functions core tools let me run my functions app locally. I want to use this as a test back end for a SPA, while the front end is served on a separate process on localhost.

If I have a blob storage input and output binding, how can I mock these when running azure functions core tools?

Eg I have a `post` HTTP triggered function `updateBlob` which takes the request body and just appends the string to the existing blob.

When I run this locally with azure functions can I mock out the blob input/output bindings so that it just reads and writes to a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `Azurite` which will emulate the entire Azure Storage
  Account and not just blob storage.
- Azurite is directly available as vs code extension. Just search
  Azurite under the extension tab and click install.
  [image]
- To start a blob service, press f1 and then select `Azurite: Start blob Service` in the popup window, this will emulate the blob storage at a
  particular address.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json&tabs=visual-studio-code) on azurite.

Comment: Thanks! What about mocking other outputs like service bus?

Comment: currently there is not emulator for azure service bus